# How to validate an entered value is a color

Tags: java, android

I am fetching a data from firebase console in my android app. I am trying to validate if the value is equal to any acceptable color before accepting it in my app to avoid crash when an incorrect data is entered like fff instead of #fff which is a color, in java. 
Is there a way to validate colors value in java.

Comment: A single regex should do the trick : a # followed by either 3 or 6 numbers or characters from a to f.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [Color#parseColor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor(java.lang.String)) method.

> Parse the color string and return the corresponding color-int. If the string cannot be parsed, throws an IllegalArgumentException exception.
>
> Supported formats are:
>    - #RRGGBB
>    - #AARRGGBB
>
> The following names are also accepted: red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray, darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy, olive, purple, silver, and teal.

The method is provided by the `Color` class in android.

Instead of that, you can try the following Pattern to parse if it's valid:
`#([0-9a-f]{3}|[0-9a-f]{6}|[0-9a-f]{8})`

Pattern usage in java:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("#([0-9a-f]{3}|[0-9a-f]{6}|[0-9a-f]{8})");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
if (matcher.matches() {
    //todo do something it is valid
}
```

Usage of the `Color#parseColor` method

```
try {
    Color color = Color.parseColor(myColorString);
    // color is a valid color
} catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
    // This color string is not valid
}
```

Comment: Can you please hint me better with a sample code the parseColor way of getting it so i can understand better. @CodeMatrix

Comment: @Joseph.A. Check [this](https://alvinalexander.com/source-code/android/how-create-color-hexadecimal-color-string-android) out it should help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression to do so, in which case the Pattern class is what you need:

```
Pattern colorPattern = Pattern.compile("#([0-9a-f]{3}|[0-9a-f]{6}|[0-9a-f]{8})");
Matcher m = colorPattern.matcher(yourInputString);
boolean isColor = m.matches();
```